# The contrast with the background doesn't allow to easily see the numbers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

The background used for reputation gained on accepted answers don't allow to easily see the reputation change. The background should be slightly lighter.

[image: screenshot]

The same problem is present in the flagging dialog box, where the number of available flags is not easily visible.

[image: screenshot]

This doesn't happen on an iPod.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed. The following screenshot shows what I see from Safari, which is the browser I used to take the previous screenshot.

[image: screenshot]